# НЕ с прилагательным характерный

Tags: грамматика, частица-не

***"Такое положение Витгенштейн считает не характерным для Вещи."***

Предложение  из "Логико-философского трактата"  философа Людвига Витгенштейна.

По какому правилу выбрана раздельная форма написания НЕ в данном случае (*считает не характерным для Вещи*)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раздельное с эпитетом написание означает отрицание того, о чём идёт речь (и часто сочетается с противопоставлением), а слитное написание — утверждение противоположного. Напр., «не любимый» означает просто отсутствие чувства любви к объекту (и присутствие безразличия к нему), а «нелюбимый» — наличие антипатии. Видимо, Витгенштейн считает, что упомянутое положение всего лишь не обязательно свойственно Вещи, а не является принципиально несвойственным ей.

Comment: Я проголосовал за ваш хороший ответ, но хотелось бы немного дополнить.  Характерно = что-то всегда или почти всегда проявляет определенную характеристику. Нехарактерно = что-то никогда или почти никогда не проявляет определенную характеристику. Не характерно = отрицается, что всегда (или почти всегда), но не утверждается, что никогда (или почти никогда).

Comment: @Егор, спасибо за ответ, мне кажется он наиболее ясным и достаточным.

Answer (score 3):

СЧИТАЕТ НЕ ХАРАКТЕРНЫМ - сказуемое с  полузнаменательной в данном предложении связкой СЧИТАЕТ.

Прилагательное с НЕ в функции сказуемого передает общеотрицательный смысл предложения и потому пишется раздельно. [Культура письменной речи](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53)

Привожу цитату: "...прилагательное с не в функции сказуемого передает общеотрицательный смысл предложения и потому пишется раздельно, а прилагательное с не в функции определения может и не передавать отрицательного смысла — такие прилагательные, как и качественные, называют новые понятия, с противоположным смыслом, хотя к ним обычно бывает затруднительно подобрать синонимы без не; ср.: Сумма не круглая. — Счет на некруглую сумму; Этот человек не здешний. — Кто-то нездешний в часовне сидит (Жук.)".

Ср.: *Такое положение не характерно для Вещи.*

Comment: Разве Иван что-нибудь спрашивал про сказуемое?

Comment: Я могу привести триллион примеров, где прилагательное с ‟не” пишется слитно в функции сказуемого. ‟Он нехороший”,  ‟Дом недорогой”, ‟Колбаса несвежая”, ‟Автор неизвестный” и так далее .

Comment: Если что, слово ‟считаться” ничего не меняет. Такая внешность считается непривлекательной. Такое поведение он считал непрактичным.

Comment: «Я могу привести триллион примеров, где прилагательное с ‟не” пишется слитно в функции сказуемого» — да откуда взялось «сказуемое»? Разве про него кто-нибудь спрашивал? «Если что, слово ‟считаться” ничего не меняет» — и о слове «считаться» вроде бы тоже вопроса не было.

Comment: Была дана ссылка на правило, где есть бредовое примечание, в котором сказано, что прилагательные в роли сказуемого пишутся с НЕ раздельно.

Comment: Ребята, да что с вами? Читайте ответ внимательно, пожалуйста. И будьте корректны по возможности. Даже тогда, когда с чем-то не согласны. Я о выпаде со словом "бредовое". Не всё, что вам кажется непонятным или что вы не приемлете, следует считать "бредовым".

Comment: «Читайте ответ внимательно, пожалуйста» — и Розенталя, пожалуйста, тоже читайте внимательно) «Правило обычно распространяется на прилагательные, выступающие в роли сказуемого» — ОБЫЧНО, а не «обязательно»! См. там же: «Примечание. В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование текста и, как следствие, двоякое написание:
эта задача нетрудная (утверждается «легкость»);
эта задача не трудная (отрицается «трудность»);
перед нами необычное явление (т. е. редкое);
перед нами не обычное явление (мыслится противопоставление: явление не обычное, а исключительное)». Так что да: читаем внимательно)

Comment: Какой-то бой с ветряными мельницами))).

Answer (score 2):

> ***Такое положение Витгенштейн считает не характерным для Вещи.***
>
> По какому правилу выбрана раздельная форма написания НЕ в данном
> случае (*считает не характерным для Вещи*)?

Ср.:

***считает*** (вовсе/отнюдь…) ***не характерным для…***

***считает*** (очень/достаточно…) ***нехарактерным для…***

**Правила допускают в таких контекстах как слитное, так и раздельное написание *не* с прилагательным.**

---

См. [**«Полный академический справочник» под ред. Лопатина:**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79)

**§ 149…** При отсутствии в контексте слов, помогающих распознать отрицание или утверждение и, следовательно, отличить частицу ***не*** от приставки ***не-***, пишущий должен проверить, какие слова — усиливающие отрицание или подчеркивающие утверждение — возможны по смыслу в данном контексте.

При возможности подстановки слов, выражающих противопоставление или усиливающих отрицание (*вовсе, отнюдь* и др., см. § 147), ***не*** пишется раздельно, напр.: <…> ***Погода была*** (нисколько) ***не жаркая…***

При возможности подстановки слов, подчеркивающих утверждение (*очень, достаточно* и др., см. § 148, п. 4), ***не*** пишется слитно, напр.: <…> ***Погода была*** (достаточно) ***нежаркая…***

**Примечание.** В отличие от причастий (см. § 150), при любых зависимых словах (кроме слов, усиливающих отрицание, см. § 147, п. 2) написание таких прилагательных с ***не*** остается слитным, напр.: *несвойственная ей роль…*

Таким образом, пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака — и тогда написать ***не*** отдельно от следующего слова (напр.: ***он не здоров…***) или утверждение признака — и тогда написать ***не*** слитно (ср.: ***он нездоров…***). От выбора написания будет зависеть и понимание написанного читающими.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79

Comment: "*Cчитает вовсе/отнюдь не характерным*" не звучит без противопоставления. Хорошо звучит так: *Он вовсе/отнюдь не считает характерным.* Дело в том, что глагол "считает" один из тех, что указывают на качество (с ними отрицание неудачно). Нужно ещё и стилистику учитывать, а грамматически подставить эти слова можно чуть ли не всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, из-за противопоставления (*не таким, а другим*):
*Такое положение Витгенштейн считает не характерным для Вещи. Он считает его вот таким.*
Иначе желательно написать слитно: *считает (каким?) нехарактерным*. Это же перевод, могли перевести и не совсем удачно.

Может быть, из-за зависимых слов — *для Вещи*. С ними отрицание целесообразней.
Но у Розенталя сказано, что зависимые слова, **как правило**, не влияют (влияют на написание НЕ с причастиями):
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77 (пункт 6)

Comment: Примечание: играет роль структура, не всегда отрицание удачно.